# 4GB USB Stick is only 1.37GB now?

Tags: partition, usb-drive

I wanted to put a `.ISO` file on my USB stick using `dd`.

But, instead of using: `dd if=/my/iso of=/dev/sdb` I did `dd if=/my/iso of=/dev/sdb1` first.

And because I wanted to rectify my mistake, I also did `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` and `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb1`.

Go figure, now something is broken.

I tried creating a new partition table. But that didn't help.

Is there a way to get the USB Stick back to it's old capacity?

Comment: This type of question belongs in SuperUser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you `dd` an image to a flash drive, the drive will be divided in 2 parts: the image partition with the image's size and a blank part. That's normal.

To get your drive go like before, just format it: `mkfs.vfat -I /dev/sdb` (as root).

Comment: Sounds promising. I will try soon.

Answer (score 1):

You have overwritten the partition table with an ISO file system.

The general expectation is that if a device contains an ISO file system, then that describes the entire contents of the media, and no further partitions are present, because that is how normal data CDs work. The system expects the rest of the media to be inaccessible, again because that is what would happen with a data CD, and does not try to look further in order to avoid read errors.

On the block level, the correct device dimensions are reported, so when you create a new partition table with `fdisk`, this table will describe the full size.

Comment: I tried exactly that, but it didn't work in my case.

Comment: The ISO filesystem starts at an offset of 32kB (0x8000). If that signature is not overwritten, it still shows up as valid. You can explicitly nuke that signature (`wipefs` should know how, or `dd` with an appropriate offset)

Comment: The above answer worked for me, but a huge +1 for the additional information on what happened to the drive.